# Make divisions and sections in Angular ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have built a table using ui-grid. it has a header and footer. Now I want to split the table in to two by adding a division at the center. something just like the footer but at the center of the table. Is this possible.

Thanks

Comment: You could make another column between the two.  Is that what you are after?

Comment: Hey Davin, I want to split it horizontally.

Comment: Then you probably need 2 separate grids.